# Simple Flutter Slide Left Animation?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want some nested UI widgets to slide into a Column, from left (off screen) to right (on  screen). The Column has an Expanded with a "flex: 4" and a Container... Basically, I want to animate this interior Container, with all that it contains.)

Can someone show me some dead simple code, or a link to code, that does this animation?  My googling is returning some very big and complicated examples.  I need a "Hello World," not 500 lines of code!

(I come from the HTML/CSS/Javascript world, and I know using Jquery I could pull this with pretty lightweight code.  Maybe I got spoiled? Though I am loving Flutter!)

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code for horizontal scroll with bouncing physics

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Horizontal List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
          height: 200.0,
          child: ListView(
             physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            // This next line does the trick.
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```